# How to create a table in Hive with a column of data type array<map<string, string>>

Tags: arrays, dictionary, hive

I am trying to create a table which has a complex data type. And the data types are listed below.

1. array
2. map
3. array< map < String,String> >

I am trying to create a data structure of 3 type . Is it ever possible to create in Hive? My table DDL looks like below.

```
create table complexTest(names array<String>,infoMap map<String,String>, deatils array<map<String,String>>)           
row format delimited                                                                                       
fields terminated by '/'                                                                                   
collection items terminated by '|'                                                                         
map keys terminated by '='                                                                                 
lines terminated by '\n';
```

And my sample data looks like below.

```
Abhieet|Test|Complex/Name=abhi|age=31|Sex=male/Name=Test,age=30,Sex=male|Name=Complex,age=30,Sex=female
```

Whever i am querying the data from the table i am getting the below values

```
["Abhieet"," Test"," Complex"]  {"Name":"abhi","age":"31","Sex":"male"} [{"Name":null,"Test,age":null,"31,Sex":null,"male":null},{"Name":null,"Complex,age":null,"30,Sex":null,"female":null}]
```

Which is not i am expecting. Could you please help me to find out what should be the DDL if it ever possible for data type `array< map < String,String>>`

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible using the inbuilt serde. If you know in advance what the values in your maps are going to be, then I think a better way of approaching this would be to convert your input data to JSON, and then use [the Hive json serde](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjb_ITBkITGAhULPZIKHdo0AD4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frcongiu%2FHive-JSON-Serde&ei=iKd3VduYOYv6yATa6YDwAw&usg=AFQjCNFidoUS5dlHBN88wcLFc6_CiAfXxg&bvm=bv.95039771,d.aWw):

Sample data:

```
{'Name': ['Abhieet', 'Test', 'Complex'],
'infoMap': {'Sex': 'male', 'Name': 'abhi', 'age': '31'},
 'details': [{'Sex': 'male', 'Name': 'Test', 'age': '30'}, {'Sex': 'female', 'Name': 'Complex', 'age': '30'}]
 }
```

Table definition code:

```
create table complexTest
(
names array<string>,
infomap struct<Name:string,
               age:string,
               Sex:string>,
details array<struct<Name:string,
               age:string,
               Sex:string>>
)
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled with array of structs using the following query.

```
create table complexStructArray(custID String,nameValuePairs array<struct< key:String, value:String>>) row format delimited fields terminated by '/' collection items terminated by '|' map keys terminated by '=' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Sample data:

> 101/Name=Madhavan|age=30
>
> 102/Name=Ramkumar|age=31

Though struct allows duplicate key values unlike Map, above query should handle the ask if the data is having unique key values.

select query would give the output as follows.

> hive> select * from complexStructArray;
>
> 101     [{"key":"Name","value":"Madhavan"},{"key":"age","value":"30"}]
>
> 102     [{"key":"Name","value":"Ramkumar"},{"key":"age","value":"31"}]

Answer (score 0):

Sample data: {"Name": ["Abhieet", "Test", "Complex"],"infoMap": {"Sex":"male", "Name":"abhi", "age":31},"details": [{"Sex":"male", "Name":"Test", "age":30}, {"Sex":"female", "Name":"Complex", "age":30}]}

Table definition code:

```html
#hive>
create table complexTest
(names array<string>,infomap struct<Name:string,
               age:string,
               Sex:string>,details array<struct<Name:string,
               age:string,
               Sex:string>>)
row format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive table can be created with parquet as file format.

Sample schema:

```
create table complexTest(
names array<String>,
infoMap struct<sex:string, name:string, age:string>, 
deatils array<struct<sex:string, name:string, age:string>>
)
stored as parquet
```